# Set div's height to 100% then subtract specific amount?

Tags: jquery

I've tried doing multiple things to get this working but can't seem to get it working.
I have a div that is auto-fixed to the bottom. There is a content box which stretches the height of the page and I need it to stop at the bottom where it hits the bottom div.
Can anyone lead me in the correct direction?

Comment: Do you have any code we can see? A working fiddle would be ideal.

Comment: I'll add some code in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i misunderstood you, but seems to be what you are looking for:

```
$('#content-box').height($(window).height()-$('#bottom').height());
```

Comment: Honestly, ŁukaszBachman's answer is in a way a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with plain CSS, only via Java Script. However, there is an easy solution which is some sort of a hack, but works.

The hack is to apply `margin-bottom` CSS property with value equal to the height of mentioned footer. That should push the content from the bottom of the page, so that both footer and content are displayed correctly.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bS7tz/

Comment: Dang, didn't even think about this.

Comment: Clever one! Nicely done! My daily vote limit reached, im sorry.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me because mine uses Absolute positioning.

Comment: Could you perhaps share a fiddle? Could help out to provide working solution.